# Difficulty to create the 3D plot of the Linear Schrödinger equation (Fourier Transform)

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, graphics3d, fourier-analysis

I am trying to solve the linear Schrödinger equation with Fourier transform as follows. Although analytically I was able to solve it and create the graphs I wanted. I have difficulty making the corresponding graph when I solve the problem numerically. Can you explain to me what is my mistake in the following code?

**Analytical solution**

```
Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_] = Exp[-x^2]
u[x_, t_, v_] = 
 Integrate[(Exp[-(I*Pi)/(4) + I*(x - y)^2/(4*v*t)])*
    f[y], {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
   Assumptions -> {v > 0, t > 0}]/(Sqrt[4 Pi*v*t])
eik5 = Plot3D[Abs[u[x, t, 0.25]]^2, {x, -25, 25}, {t, 0.05, 30}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 250]
```

[image]

Numerical solution

```
(*  Fourier tranform for the equation  Subscript[u, \
t](x,t)=i*v*Subscript[u, xx](x,t) *)
FourierSinTransform[ D[u[x, t], {t, 1}], x, \[Omega]] == 
 FourierSinTransform[ I*v* D[u[x, t], {x, 2}], x, \[Omega], 
  FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]
ode = D[
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(\(\ \ \)\(u\)\), \(^\)]\)[\[Omega], t], {t, 
     1}] == I*v*\[Omega]*(-\[Omega]*
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(u\), \(^\)]\)[\[Omega], t] - 2*T0);
sol = DSolve[ode, 
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(u\), \(^\)]\)[\[Omega], t], t]
FourierSinTransform[u[x, 0], x, \[Omega]] == 
 FourierSinTransform[f[x], x, \[Omega], FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]
ic = 
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(u\), \(^\)]\)[\[Omega], 0] == 
  FourierSinTransform[f[x], x, \[Omega], FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]
sol = DSolve[{ode, ic}, 
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(u\), \(^\)]\)[\[Omega], t], t]

\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(u\), \(^\)]\)[\[Omega]_, t_] = -((
  2 E^(-I t v \[Omega]^2) (-T0 + 
     E^(I t v \[Omega]^2)
       T0 + \[Omega] DawsonF[\[Omega]/2]))/\[Omega])
u[x_, t_] = InverseFourierSinTransform[
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(u\), \(^\)]\)[\[Omega], t], \[Omega], x, 
  FourierParameters -> {1, -1}, Assumptions -> {x > 0}]
T0 = 1;
Plot[Abs[u[x, t]]^2, {x, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All]
```

You can download the notebook of my project from [Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2933433)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too large in comment:

It is very simple actually. The `InverseFourierSinTransform` in your notebook did not evaluate. Then you are trying to plot it. Here is screen shot from your notebook near the end

[image]

You should really always make sure each command completes OK before using its output in the next command.

V 13.2.1 on windows 10

Comment: Why the code did not evaluate?

Comment: @AthanasiosParaskevopoulos I do not know.  Mathematica just could not do it. May be there is a workaround or may be it is too hard. But this is separate issue. You could post separate question on this part only. I am just answering the question on why you are getting these errors from the plot command.

Comment: Οh ok!!! Thank you. I will do it